# Simulated Annealing InitialPoints option

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I have a cost function that depends on 4 parameters: `CostFunction[{tx,ty,tz,ox}]`.

I used `NMinimize[]` function with `SimulatedAnnealing` method to determine its minimum. I looked for an example that uses the `InitialPoints` option but I did not find any. For this reason I am posting my question.

My code is like this (I cannot post the `CostFunction[]`):

```
  NMinimize[{
        CostFunction[{tx, ty, tz, ox}],
        tx >= 0 && tx <= a, ty >= 0 && ty <= b, tz >= 0 && tz <=c, ox >=0 && ox <= d},
  {tx,ty,tz,ox},
  Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", "PerturbationScale" -> 3, "SearchPoints" -> 10}]
```

The above code works correctly but when I add the `"InitialPoints"->{0,0,0,0}`, I receive the following error:

> `NMinimize::parchange: "Inappropriate parameter:
>   \!\(\"InitialPoints\"\) -> {0,0,0,0}, changed to Automatic"`

Another option is not very clear `"RandomSeed"` ?

What is wrong, please?

Answer (score 8):

Borrowing the function from the documentation in the [optimization tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html)

```
Clear[a, f]; 
a = Reverse /@ Distribute[{{-32, -16, 0, 16, 32}, {-32, -16, 0, 16, 32}},  List]; 
f = 1/(0.002 + Plus @@ MapIndexed[1/(#2[[1]] + Plus @@ (({x, y} - #1)^6)) &, a]);

NMinimize[f, {{x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}}, Method -> {"SimulatedAnnealing", 
  "InitialPoints" -> Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -45, 45, 5}, {j, -45, 45, 5}], 1]}]
{0.998004, {x -> -31.9783, y -> -31.9783}}
```

I think the problem with your use of `InitialPoints` is that you have to give it a list of points, and not a single point! `Randomseed` is used in many functions to specify a starting point for the random number generator so that all runs of the algorithm use the same set of random numbers (this may be desired for repeatability).

Comment: Ok! Thanks, in fact I am developping a program to align each frame from a video with a model. In ieration K, I minimize the costfunction[] to get the optimal rigid transformation between model and video frame, in the next iteration k+1, I want to inject the transformation given in the iteration k as initial  point in order to get rapidly the convergence in the next iteration (k+1). Thanks !

Comment: Have you looked at `ImageAlign` or `ImageCorrespondingPoints`. These are likely to do a better job than a direct optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But  I need precisily to do direct optimization, because in my case, I can not take a corresponding points. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please, What is the exactly role of the option  InitialPoints. Going back to my exemple above, I pick InitialPoints like this Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, -500, 500, 50}, {j, -500, 500, 
    50}, {k, -90, 90, 20}, {l, -90, 90, 20}], 3]; The algorithm become very slow. I think that, it uses the InitialPoints as a starting points and from each points it look for an optimum, for this reason it is slow! And what is the relation between the option SearchPoints and InitialPoints? is the algorithm takes the SearchPoints from the IntialPoints?

Comment: Simulated annealing works by starting at a large number of initial guesses and then moving in (some kind of mostly) downhill direction until it converges. You want to start at a large variety of initial guesses in order not to miss any minima.

Comment: But, the number of starting point is given as function of number of variables, SearchPoints =Min[2*d,50].

Comment: That's how many there are. `InitialPoints` lets you specify their value.

Comment: Yes, I know taht but the InitialPoints option is not very clear for me. I want just to know what is the exactly role of this option. Is there any explication of this implementation bcause in documentation center it is not very clear for some option. thanks

Comment: Is there any possibility to show the SearchPoints at each iteration using StepMonitor?